# Code not returning the right index

Tags: c++, c

I'm tring to solve a small problem. I have two strings. `s1` and `s2`. I want my function to return the first index of `s1` that has a character not present in the string `s2`. This is my code.

```
int cad_nenhum_dos (char s1[], char s2[]){
int i,j;
    for (i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
            for (j=0;s2[j]!='\0';j++)
                    if (s1[i]!=s2[j]) return i;
    }
return -1;
}
```

If I run `s1="hello"` `s2="hellm"`, the result should be index `4`, because `s1[4]='o'` and `"o"` is not present in `s2`... But I allways get `0` when I run this. The `-1` works fine if the strings are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Think what it's doing. Any time *any* of the second's characters don't match, it returns `i`. Try it with `s1 = "hello"` and `s2 = "hhhhh"` and you'll get `1`.

Comment: Hi there @chris. Yeah, i know what's the problem ;) I'm not looking through the complete string, so if any char doesn't match at the begining it will return, even if it repeats ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner loop you need to break out when you find a character the same -- as it stands you're returning when there are *any* different characters in the second string, even if an earlier one was the same. You want something like

```
        for (j=0;s2[j]!='\0';j++)
                if (s1[i]==s2[j]) break;
        if (s2[j]==0)
                return i;
```

I.e. you want to return the `i`th character of the first string when you've made you way through the *whole* of the second string without having found that character.

Comment: Oh i see. So i am comparing chars that may be diferent now, but i can have them repeated after the current index... okey thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For programming exercises at the introductory level it's a good idea to carefully execute the code manually (step through yourself and see what's happening).
As TooTone suggested, you need to break out of the loop when you find a match:

```
for (int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    bool charFound = false;
    for (int j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        if (s1[i] == s2[j])
        {
            charFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! charFound)
        return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the inner for-loop is comparing first letter of the first string against all the letters in the second string.

Comment: well that's the idea... i want to look if the char in the index in string 1 is in any position in string2.

Answer (score 0):

```
int cad_nenhum_dos (char s1[], char s2[])
   {
   int i,j;

   for(i=0; s1[i]; i++)
      {
      if(s1[i] != s2[j]) 
         return(i);
      }

   return(-1);
   }
```

Comment: Hi @MahonriMoriancumer, why do you use the () on the returns?

Comment: This answer could use some explanation. Why does it work and why doesn't the original code?

Comment: @PedroLino Some programmers like to use parentheses around return values, I think it makes them feel like it's just another function call. I think it's a bad idea for exactly the same reason, as do most programmers.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, i don't know if this works, i haven't tried it, i've done a solution myself when i got what the problem was :) But yeah, i don't understand the point of parentheses in the return call... I guess there is no point to it, since is a single value